# Get data from google cloud to dialogflow

Tags: cloud, fetch, response, dialogflow-es

I have problem when I want to get responses from a google cloud datastore where I have created entities. My code in the fulfillment inline editor is:

```
use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require ('actions-on-google');
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
// Instantiate a datastore client
const datastore = Datastore();
//INTENTS
const TICKET_INTENT = 'ticket';
//ENTITIES
const DISPLAYED_ICON_ENTITY = 'Displayed_Icon';
//APP
const app = dialogflow();

//QUERIES
const queryNoDisplayed = datastore.createQuery('responses').filter('ID', '=', 'DISP_ICON');

app.intent(TICKET_INTENT, (conv) => {
   const displayed_icon = conv.parameters[DISPLAYED_ICON_ENTITY].toLowerCase();

   if(displayed_icon == "undisplayed")
   {
       return datastore.runQuery(queryNoDisplayed).then(results => {
            conv.ask(results[0][0].SolutionaText);
        });
       //conv.ask("You aren't added into security group. Please, contact HELP DESK");
});   

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

When I use:

```
return datastore.runQuery(queryNoDisplayed).then(results => {
            conv.ask(results[0][0].SolutionText);
        });
```

It doesn't give a response and say that the property solutionTest is not finded. Anyone can help me?